# Read lines from a file and output as options for a dropdown

Tags: php, forms, post, transform

I have $data which contains something like this and changes often:

```
backup 2011-04-15 16:39:18.559965.zip
backup 2011-04-15 16:39:56.289656.zip
backup 2011-04-15 16:41:34.463754.zip
backup 2011-04-15 16:41:54.089134.zip
backup 2011-04-15 16:42:18.742616.zip
backup 2011-04-16 13:12:33.083622.zip
backup 2011-04-16 13:14:53.387308.zip
backup 2011-04-17 00:30:32.591461.zip
```

How can i make that it will transform it into a Dropdown list, so people can choose from and i can use result as $_POST['file']?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Read text using **fopen()**
2. Split text into array using **explode()**
3. Loopt trough array using **foreach()**
4. **echo** elements between option tags.

**EDIT**

I did not provide any code because you should be able to write this yourself following the steps above. Simply use Google to find out how these functions work. You can only learn PHP by implementing things yourself. Don't expect people to write complete scripts for you.

Anyways, this should be working :)

```
$path = "files.txt";
$file = fopen($path, 'r');
$data = fread($file, filesize($path));
fclose($file);

$lines =  explode(PHP_EOL,$data);
echo '<select name="file">';
foreach($lines as $line) {
  echo '<option value="'. urlencode($line).'">'.$line.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

You can also use file_get_contents() instead of fopen().

```
$data = file_get_contents("files.txt");
```

**EDIT**

Added **file()** like recommended by Wiseguy

```
$lines = file('files.txt');
echo '<select name="file">';
foreach($lines as $line) {
  echo '<option value="'. urlencode($line).'">'.$line.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example?

Comment: Working example has been added.

Comment: Or, shorter yet, simply `$lines = file('files.txt');`

Comment: Thanks for making me aware of `file()` !

Answer (score 1):

```
$lines = explode($data);
echo '<select name="file">';
foreach($lines as $line) {
  echo '<option value="', $line, '">', $line, '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: You, probably, want to repalce those variable seperators `,` with a dot (`.`). hehe.

Comment: @Tom Actually, `echo` works that way. From http://php.net/echo – _"if you want to pass more than one parameter to echo(), the parameters must not be enclosed within parentheses."_

Comment: Tom, when using echo, comma are faster than dot since the Zend engine doesn't need to concatenate the strings (a slow operation).

Comment: Oh, thats a new one for me, noted! Gotta love the way how you can learn in SO.